# Flask app-builder how to make REST API with file items

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, flask-appbuilder

I'm making a REST api that files can be uploaded based in MODEL-VIEW in flask-appbuilder like this.
But I don't know how to call REST API (POST /File).
I tried several different ways. but I couldn't.
Let me know the correct or the alternative ways.

[client code]

```
file = {'file':open('test.txt', 'rb'),'description':'test'}
requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=file)
```

==> Failed

model.py

```
class Files(Model):
    __tablename__ = "project_files"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file = Column(FileColumn, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(150))

    def download(self):
        return Markup(
            '<a href="'
            + url_for("ProjectFilesModelView.download", filename=str(self.file))
            + '">Download</a>'
        )

    def file_name(self):
        return get_file_original_name(str(self.file))
```

view.py

```
class FileApi(ModelRestApi):
    resource_name = "File"
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Files)
    allow_browser_login = True


appbuilder.add_api(FileApi)
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileColumn` is only a string field that saves the file name in the database. The actual file is saved to `config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`.
This is taken care of by `flask_appbuilder.filemanager.FileManager`.

Furthermore, `ModelRestApi` assumes that you are POSTing JSON data. In order to upload files, I followed [Flask's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/), which suggests to send a `multipart/form-data` request. Because of this, one needs to override `ModelRestApi.post_headless()`.

This is my solution, where I also make sure that when a `Files` database row
is deleted, so is the relative file from the filesystem.

```
from flask_appbuilder.models.sqla.interface import SQLAInterface
from flask_appbuilder.api import ModelRestApi
from flask_appbuilder.const import API_RESULT_RES_KEY
from flask_appbuilder.filemanager import FileManager

from flask import current_app, request

from marshmallow import ValidationError
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

from app.models import Files


class FileApi(ModelRestApi):
    resource_name = "file"
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Files)

    def post_headless(self):
        if not request.form or not request.files:
            msg = "No data"
            current_app.logger.error(msg)
            return self.response_400(message=msg)

        file_obj = request.files.getlist('file')
        if len(file_obj) != 1:
            msg = ("More than one file provided.\n"
                   "Please upload exactly one file at a time")
            current_app.logger.error(msg)
            return self.response_422(message=msg)
        else:
            file_obj = file_obj[0]

        fm = FileManager()
        uuid_filename = fm.generate_name(file_obj.filename, file_obj)
        form = request.form.to_dict(flat=True)

        # Add the unique filename provided by FileManager, which will
        # be saved to the database. The original filename can be 
        # retrieved using 
        # flask_appbuilder.filemanager.get_file_original_name()
        form['file'] = uuid_filename

        try:
            item = self.add_model_schema.load(
                    form,
                    session=self.datamodel.session)
        except ValidationError as err:
            current_app.logger.error(err)
            return self.response_422(message=err.messages)

        # Save file to filesystem
        fm.save_file(file_obj, item.file)

        try:
            self.datamodel.add(item, raise_exception=True)
            return self.response(
                201,
                **{API_RESULT_RES_KEY: self.add_model_schema.dump(
                    item, many=False),
                    "id": self.datamodel.get_pk_value(item),
                   },
                )
        except IntegrityError as e:
            # Delete file from filesystem if the db record cannot be
            # created
            fm.delete_file(item.file)
            current_app.logger.error(e)
            return self.response_422(message=str(e.orig))

    def pre_delete(self, item):
        """
        Delete file from filesystem before removing the record from the 
        database
        """
        fm = FileManager()
        current_app.logger.info(f"Deleting {item.file} from filesystem")
        fm.delete_file(item.file)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is an excellent Approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
from app.models import Project, ProjectFiles

class DataFilesModelView(ModelView):
datamodel = SQLAInterface(ProjectFiles)

label_columns = {"file_name": "File Name", "download": "Download"}
add_columns = ["file", "description", "project"]
edit_columns = ["file", "description", "project"]
list_columns = ["file_name", "download"]
show_columns = ["file_name", "download"]
```

Last add the view to the menu.

```
appbuilder.add_view(DataFilesModelView,"File View")
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. but I need REST /POST API to upload a file.